# Analysis of Cloud Resources Allocations

Tags: cloud, openstack, resource-management

I'm trying to go through Openstack Cloud to find anything in the API that lets me get the data of Cloud Resource Allocation on hardware level. Does anyone know about any library or tool to poll hardware level resource allocation data?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, OpenStack itself does not include monitoring facilities for your **physical hosts**. Depending on how you deploy OpenStack, you should look into deploying a traditional server monitoring solution alongside your OpenStack components.

The OpenStack Wiki lists a number of monitoring solutions and monitoring scripts others have used with their OpenStack clouds: [OpenStack Monitoring Tools](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Operations/Tools#Monitoring_and_Trending).

In addition to monitoring your physical hosts, you need to monitor core OpenStack **infrastructure components** (relation database e.g. MySQL, RabbitMQ, Memcache etc.). Again, a large number of monitoring solutions and plugins exist for these (e.g. [Telegraf](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf), [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/)).

OpenStack Nova includes an API for querying **hypervisor state**. You can use this to get a glimpse on Nova's load: [Hypervisor Details API](http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/?expanded=show-host-details-detail,list-hypervisors-details-detail). This API could provide the monitoring information you may be looking for (i.e. "how much spare capacity do my hypervisors have?"). Your question is a little unclear here. 
However *it is not a replacement for properly monitoring physical host health + infrastructure components*.